# movement similar to "f" but you can specify more than one character as search criteria

Tags: neovim, search, movement

Say we got this sentence:

```
pafpaf apfa fpa i apa panda pafas af
```

I would like to quickly move the cursor from the start of the line to the beginning of the word `panda`. I could do `6fp`, but what takes time is counting the number of `p`'s. It would be much faster if I simply could search for the word in the current line and instantly jump to it.

Now, I could just do a search for it: `/panda` hit enter and then `:noh` (to remove highlighting), but having to write out `:noh` every time is annoying and time-consuming.

Does anyone have any suggestion for a solution?

Comment: Vim-cool might solve your hlsearch problem (it has for me) https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool

Comment: There's [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak). With *label-mode*, you input 2 characters, and a key to jump to a desired location --- no need to count the number of p's.

...and with some tweaking, you can input n characters instead of 2 (although 2 chars is sufficient for most cases). See [here](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak/blob/65e5e4668371152c6ef7a6269c6a6b960cef21b4/doc/sneak.txt#L375-L411)

Comment: As a habit, instead of `:noh` I do `/aslkdlakjsd` which is quite fast to type.

Comment: There are several plugins that extend the default `f` and `t` motions, have a look at: https://github.com/goldfeld/vim-seek https://github.com/chrisbra/improvedft  https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-extended-ft  https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic

Comment: Agree with @ChristianBrabandt.  I use vim-sneak all the time.  Maybe not as much as I use easymotion; but at least as much as I use bare f.

Answer (score 2):

I use a mapping `<LEADER>/` so I can toggle highlighting on and off:

```
nnoremap <silent><expr> <LEADER>/
            \ (&hls && v:hlsearch ? ':nohls' : ':set hls')."\n"
```

I found that the above would highlight the last searched term when I opened
vim, which I found irritating, but I fixed that by adding `| noh` to the
setting `hlsearch`:

```
set hlsearch | noh " highlight matches for searched (turn off when sourcing)
```

Also it's worth mentioning that after using `fp` (or `Fp`, `tp`, `Tp` etc.) you
can use `;` and `,` to jump to the next/previous occurrence of 'p' (or whatever you
searched for). So in cases where you do a `f` motion, and don't jump right to
the letter you want because you didn't notice that same letter occurring
sooner, you can just hit `;` a few times to get there... and `,` to go back one if you over-shoot.